# close css hover dopdown menu after click on item

Tags: css, dropdown

I'm using pure css dropdown menu. But after clicking the menu item, the dropdown menu is alway displayed. It will be hidden when I give my mouse out of the menu.
How can I close the pure css hover dropdown menu after clicking on the menu item? 
Thanks for your advice.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
</style>  
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="product" href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a onClick="document.getElementById('product').innerHTML = 'Laptop selected!'; return false;" href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use js to do that like setting display none once you click on any menu item. Create a css class for display none like hide and add class to menu once any item is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/6a3xogfj/2/

What I did was adding classes to distinguish `.open` and `.closed` dropdown status.

**CSS**

```
ul li ul.dropdown.closed { display: none; }
ul li ul.dropdown.open { display: block; }
```

The rest was done via jQuery.

**JS**

```
$('a#product').on('mouseover', function() {

  $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown').removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
});

$('ul.dropdown a').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('ul.dropdown').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
  $('section').removeClass('active').filter( $(this).attr('href') ).addClass('active');
  $('a#product').text( $(this).text() + " selected!");
});
```

When you hover the menu item `#product` the dropdown is set from `.closed` to `.open` and therefore shown. As soon as a dropdown item is clicked those classes are reset to close the dropdown.

Comment: You probably want to also hide the menu when the mouse hovers away. Would also be nice to have a non-JQuery example for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

What we did is oncClick hide and show it again after a blink:

```
var dropDownMenu = $('#" + clikedMenuItemId + "').next('ul'); 
dropDownMenu.hide(0, function() { 
 setTimeout(function() { 
   dropDownMenu.show(); 
 }, 
 1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to 'dismiss' the menu by setting the drop down menu style  'display: none;'  when you click a drop down element. Then bring back the drop down by setting the style 'display: '';' when you hover over the menu item. I modified your code to demonstrate this approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
</style>  
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="product" href="#" onmouseover="enableDropdown()">Products</a>
            <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="javascript:myFunction_1();">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:myFunction_2();">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:myFunction_3();">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>

<script>
  function disableDropdown()
  {
      // dismiss menu by disabling each drop down menu in UI
      document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display = 'none';
  }

  function enableDropdown()
  {
      // re-enable each drop down menu in UI
      document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display = '';
  }

  function myFunction_1()
  {
      document.getElementById('product').innerHTML = 'Laptop selected!';
      disableDropdown();
  }

  function myFunction_2()
  {
      document.getElementById('product').innerHTML = 'Monitors selected!';
      disableDropdown();
  }
  function myFunction_3()
  {
      document.getElementById('product').innerHTML = 'Printers selected!';
      disableDropdown();
  } 

</script>
```